# Issues in FiniteGroupData Character Tables

Tags: bugs, group-theory

Using `$Version == "12.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (May 10, 2021)"` and executing

```
Select[FiniteGroupData[All], 
    And[Not[MissingQ[#]], Not@SquareMatrixQ[#]] &@
    FiniteGroupData[#, "CharacterTable"] &]
```

I found that both `{"PointGroup","Oh"}` and `{"PointGroup","I"}` have character tables that are not square.  It is a theorem that they must be square.  In fact, the reason they are not square is that in both cases one of the rows is shorter than the others.

Using

```
\[Chi] = FiniteGroupData[{"PointGroup", "Oh"}, "CharacterTable"];
Length /@ \[Chi]
TableForm@\[Chi]
```

we can see that the 2nd row is 1 entry short.  Comparing to     https://www.webqc.org/symmetrypointgroup-oh.html it's clear that all the other irreps are correct, and that the `A2g` is incorrect; it has a 0 where `+1, -1` should be.  I conjecture this is due to a missing comma in Mathematica's internals, giving `1-1=0`.

Similarly,

```
\[Chi]I = FiniteGroupData[{"PointGroup", "I"}, "CharacterTable"];
Length /@ \[Chi]I
TableForm@\[Chi]I
```

shows that the trivial irrep is one entry short.  I conjecture this is due to a similar missing comma, giving implied multiplication `1 1 = 1`.

Whatever the cause, this is *certainly* a bug, and I have opened an issue with Wolfram.

Comment: Wolfram support reproduces and confirms this is a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug was resolved in version 13.0 (`$Version == "13.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 3, 2021)"`).