# Bug in Point Group Conjugacy Class Data

Tags: bugs, group-theory

I noticed that in `$Version == "13.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (November 18, 2022)"` Mathematica has conflicting `FiniteGroupData` for `{"PointGroup", "O"}`.

Evidence of the bug is that `Length[FiniteGroupData[{"PointGroup", "O"}, "ConjugacyClasses"]] !=  Length[FiniteGroupData[{"PointGroup", "O"}, "ConjugacyClassNames"]]`.

It turns out the ConjugacyClasses are correct but the ...Names are not.  The bug is that

```
{E,6Subscript[C, 4],3Subscript[C, 2] 8Subscript[C, 3],6Subsuperscript[C, 2, \[Prime]]}
```

looks to the eye like a list of length 5, but the third and putative fourth elements are not comma separated.  They happen to be in the correct order by looking at the ConjugacyClasses themselves.

I checked every finite group, not judging missing data.

```
comparison = Table[{G, FiniteGroupData[G, #] & /@ {
    "ConjugacyClasses", 
    "ConjugacyClassNames",
    "ConjugacyClassSizes"}},
    {G, FiniteGroupData[]}];
comparison = comparison /. {
    Missing["TooLarge"] -> Nothing, 
    Missing["NotAvailable"] -> Nothing
};
problems = Select[comparison, Not[Equal[#[[2]]]] &]
```

The final result is that

```
problems[[All, 1]] == {{"PointGroup", "O"}, {"PointGroup", "Th"}}
```

This is not [the first elided-comma bug I have found in `FiniteGroupData`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/252775/7936).

Comment: I have submitted a bug report to Wolfram Support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `$Version == "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)"` the example now yields `problems == {}`; the bug is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

A temporary workaround is

```
Unprotect[FiniteGroupData];
FiniteGroupData[{"PointGroup", "O"}, "ConjugacyClassNames"] = (
    FiniteGroupData[{"PointGroup", "O"}, "ConjugacyClassNames"] /. Times -> Sequence
)
FiniteGroupData[{"PointGroup", "Th"}, "ConjugacyClassNames"] = Flatten@(
    FiniteGroupData[{"PointGroup", "Th"}, "ConjugacyClassNames"] /. Times -> Reverse@*List
)
```